# Crosscompile linux dependent code on windows machine

Tags: go, compiler-errors, cross-compiling

I have an issue when trying to compile linux specific GoLang code on my windows machine

I am using, in this case, https://github.com/hidez8891/shm pretty straight off, but the only thing i get back is ".\shm.go:10:7: undefined: shmi".

GOOS is set to linux and GOARCH is set to amd64. Do anyone have any ideas, perhaps it's not even possible to do what i am trying to do. All help would be great.

Comment: I don't think you can cross-compile anything that requires cgo.

Comment: I think, you need to install gcc, because cgo may request c related details from gcc. `shmi_linux.go` is using `c.Int` type, while defining `shmi` struct. Once try installing gcc and then try.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'll try that tonight and see what I can make of it

Comment: Installed gcc but no luck trying to compile. Think i am gonna try to do it with docker instead

Comment: I ended up just using the "new" linux subsystem on windows. Very simple and the work effort to solve the issue where quite small. Thanks for the help!